# LaravelのWhereの使い方

Tags: php, laravel

whereで、A OR B　がuser_idと一致したカラムのデータ(score)を取得すると書きたいのですが、いまいちわからず、悩んでおります。

```
$score = Contract::where('a' , 'b')->where('user_id')->get();
```

これで正しいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereメソッドは
第一引数がカラム名
第二引数がオペレータ
第三引数が比較する値です。

まず`Where user_id = 'a'`を行いたい場合は

```
$score = Contract::where('user_id', "=", "a")->get();
```

ただし、第二引数のイコールは省略できるので

```
$score = Contract::where('user_id', "a")->get();
```

という書き方ができます。

これをORでつなげたい場合はorwhereメソッドをつなげて書きます。
例えば`Where user_id = 'a' OR user_id = 'b'`というWhere句を作りたい場合は

```
$score = Contract::where('user_id', "a")->orWhere('user_id', "b")->get();
```

上記のように記述します。

そもそもLaravelのEloquentORMはデータベースの取り回しの理解をしている必要があります。
まずはデータベース周りのメソッドやモデルを理解をしましょう
特にWhereメソッドについてはデータベースのクエリビルダーのドキュメントに詳しく記述してあります。

参考サイト
https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/eloquent.html
https://readouble.com/laravel/5.7/ja/queries.html

Comment: 大変詳しく、ありがとうございます！

Comment: @ななみ もし役にたった、解決したということであれば（この回答に限らず）承認をしてみてください。参考：[回答を承認するとどうなりますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)